# How can I compare file creation time to the current time in Perl?

Tags: perl, file, time

i want to compare the current time and file creation time in Perl but both are in different format. localtime is in this format:

```
22116291110813630
```

and file creation time is

```
Today, December 29, 2008, 2:38:37 PM
```

How do i compare which one is greater and their difference?

Comment: Maybe of interest: http://www.perl.com/doc/manual/html/pod/perlfunc/stat.html

Comment: Info of how to convert dates: http://www.perl.com/pub/a/2003/03/13/datetime.html

Comment: The answer to your question is: Convert them to the same format. I suggest converting "Today, December 29, 2008" to a timestamp (number of (milli)seconds since epoch). Then it is a simple compare of two numbers

Comment: Do you really mean "creation time," which is not tracked by many file systems, or do you mean "ctime" which is the "inode change time" on Unix-like operating systems?

Answer (score 16):

It's even easier than using stat() and time()/localtime().

```
my $diff = -M $filename;
```

The -M operator returns the "age" of the file (in days since the start of the program). It's documented under the [-X functions](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) or in `perldoc -f -X`.

Comment: I know this is an old thread but I'm posting a reply anyway.

-M gives the "age" of the last modification not file creation. -C would have given the correct value as requested but I only use the -X functions (http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) in one-liners and use stat the rest of the time.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to compare values, you might want to use the number you got from [`localtime`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html) in scalar context and the inode change time that you can get from [`stat`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html):

```
               ($dev,$ino,$mode,$nlink,$uid,$gid,$rdev,$size,
                  $atime,$mtime,$ctime,$blksize,$blocks)
                      = stat($filename);
```

where:

```
                 0 dev      device number of filesystem
                 1 ino      inode number
                 2 mode     file mode  (type and permissions)
                 3 nlink    number of (hard) links to the file
                 4 uid      numeric user ID of file's owner
                 5 gid      numeric group ID of file's owner
                 6 rdev     the device identifier (special files only)
                 7 size     total size of file, in bytes
                 8 atime    last access time in seconds since the epoch
                 9 mtime    last modify time in seconds since the epoch
                10 ctime    inode change time in seconds since the epoch (*)
                11 blksize  preferred block size for file system I/O
                12 blocks   actual number of blocks allocated
```

So you want field 9:

```
$mtime = ( stat $filename )[9];
$current_time = time;

$diff = $current_time - $mtime;
```

Comment: Thanks for giving information to me.i think it is giving the diff in no of secs.anyway thanks for ur guide.Advance happy new year

Answer (score 3):

`localtime` returns a list of values in list context.  See [the localtime documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html) or [perlcheat](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlcheat.html).  In your example, it looks like those all mushed together.  In scalar context, it returns a formatted string like `Mon Dec 29 03:16:33 2008`.  On most platforms, the file inode change time will be returned from `stat` as a number of seconds since some epoch.  You should be able to directly compare that to the result of `time()` (*not* `localtime()`).

Answer (score 0):

These two functions are thanks to jimtut's answer.  fileage prints the number of seconds as an integer, perfect for usage in a shell, of a file from when it was created.  fileage is the answer to the above question, while dataage prints the same for the contents of a file as that's the answer I was looking for I'm sure these will both be useful.

```
function fileage {
  perl -e 'printf "%i\n", 60 * 60 * 24 * -C "'"${1:?Must provide a file name}"'"'
}

function dataage {
  perl -e 'printf "%i\n", 60 * 60 * 24 * -M "'"${1:?Must provide a file name}"'"'
}
```