# How to get file creation time in Unix with Perl

Tags: perl, shell, unix, unix-timestamp

How to get file creation time in unix with perl?

I have this command which displays file's last modification time:

```
perl -MPOSIX -le 'print strftime "%d %b %Y %H:%M ".$_, localtime((lstat)[9]) for @ARGV' file.txt
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/397495/how-can-i-compare-file-creation-time-to-the-current-time-in-perl

Comment: @chilemagic can you post a exact command as the answer to get the create time?

Answer (score 1):

There is not normally *file creation time* in UNIX. A new [xstat()](https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_1.2.0/gLSB/baselib-xstat-1.html) interface promises support for it, but perl doesn't use it. It is possible to write an XS-based interface to gain access to it.

In Perl on UNIX, `ctime` stands for Inode Change Time, which has nothing to do with file creation.

According to [perlport](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html#Files-and-Filesystems), `ctime` will be creation time only on Windows, but you might want to use the [Win32API::File::Time::GetFileTime()](http://search.cpan.org/~wyant/Win32API-File-Time-0.006/lib/Win32API/File/Time.pm) since it is more explicit (and will be obvious to porters) that your program depends on *creation* time instead of whatever `ctime` contains.

Answer (score 0):

You almost have it.

You just need to pass the return value from [`localtime`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/localtime.html) instead of the filename to [`strftime`](http://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html#FUNCTIONS):

```
perl -MPOSIX -e 'printf "%s %s\n", $_, strftime("%d %b %Y %H:%M", localtime((lstat)[9])) for @ARGV' file.txt
```

Outputs:

```
file.txt 10 Oct 2014 15:38
```

And even though it takes more code, I'd lean toward using [`Time::Piece`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html) and [`File::stat`](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/stat.html) to make the code more modern and readable:

```
perl -MTime::Piece -MFile::stat -e '
    printf "%s %s\n",  $_, localtime( stat($_)->mtime )->strftime("%d %b %Y %H:%M") for @ARGV
  ' file.txt
```

Comment: It still didn't get me the create time :-(

Comment: Take a look at the docs for [`stat`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html).  Perhaps you want the `ctime` instead of the `mtime`? Just be sure to read the _(*)  Not all fields are supported on all filesystem types. Notably, the ctime field is non-portable. In particular, you cannot expect it to be a "creation time"; see Files and Filesystems in perlport for details._

Comment: Take a look at the docs for stat; ctime doesn't stand for "file creation time".

Comment: I know that. Take a look at my previous comment.

Comment: It is a common misconception that `ctime` represents "creation".  `ctime` is the last change time of an inode (permissions, ownership, name) whereas `mtime` represents the last modification time of the file/directory contents.  Most generally, even when doing in situ updates with `perl -i`, its the modification time that reflects a creation instance.