# Unexpected output from perl script

Tags: perl, stat, activestate

The following script produces no output:

```
use File::stat;
use Time::localtime;
my $filename = 'c:\testfile';
my ($dev,$ino,$mode,$nlink,$uid,$gid,$rdev,$size,
              $atime,$mtime,$ctime,$blksize,$blocks)
                  = stat($filename);
print("$mtime");
```

`c:\testfile` exists.

I've seen several answers on SO -- [this, for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397495/how-can-i-compare-file-creation-time-to-the-current-time-in-perl) -- which seem to suggest that the array returned by `stat()` should have something meaningful in it, but I haven't seen that to be the case in practice.

This is 64 bit [ActivePerl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActivePerl) on Windows 7.

Does stat not do what those answers seemed to imply, or do Perl's file date/time functions not work under Windows (or 64 bit Windows, or some such?)

Comment: The built-in [`stat`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html) is not the same as `stat` from [`File::stat`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::stat) (which is not the same as [`File::Stat`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Stat)).

Comment: [ikegami already did.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28420020/176646)

Comment: "Use it appropriately" isn't an answer.

Comment: "Remove `use File::stat;`" *is* an answer, and "`File::stat` replaces `stat` with one that has a different interface" is no different from what I said in my comment (except for the links). Regardless, you have two answers now, no need for me to add another.

Comment: Except for the links. Right. His answer wasn't quite thorough enough to be a good comment. But as you mention, Sobrique did a fine job.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works fine:

```
#!perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = 'c:\Users\username\Documents\asdf23rasdf.pl';
my ($dev,  $ino,   $mode,  $nlink, $uid,     $gid, $rdev,
    $size, $atime, $mtime, $ctime, $blksize, $blocks
) = stat($filename);
print($mtime);
```

As alluded to in the comments - Perl's built-in `stat` works like the above. You don't need to use `File::Stat` or `File::stat` in order to do that. They just provide different interfaces to the same functionality.

If you want to do it with `File::stat` it goes like this:

```
use File::stat;

my $filename = 'c:\Users\username\Documents\asdf23rasdf.pl';
my $stats = stat($filename);
print( $stats -> mtime);
```

Answer (score 6):

File::stat replaces `stat` with one that has a different interface. Remove `use File::stat;` or use its `stat` appropriately.